# qt5 multiline button with multiple style for each line

Tags: c++, qt5, qpushbutton

Can I make button, that have multiple lines, and each line have different style? When I use gtkmm, I can put widgets inside buttons, so I can make vbox with two different style labels and put it into button. But it looks, like I can't insert widgets into buttons in qt. Maybe there another way, to make multiline button with different style for each line?

Sorry for my English!

Comment: Please provide code which will help others pinpoint your problem and provide better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I found a solution. I cat put layout of widgest just like in gtkmm. I just use method setLayout() of QPushButton. With this method I can put layout of multiple labels inside button.

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel( this );
QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout( this );
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton( this );
layout()->addWidget( label );
button->setLayout( layout );
```